# How can I delete all hidden buffers?

Tags: vim

I like to run Vim with `'hidden'` on.  Sometimes, though, I've got a lot of hidden buffers hanging around and I'd like to kill them all.  What command can I use to `:bdelete` every hidden buffer in the buffer list?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
function DeleteHiddenBuffers()
    let tpbl=[]
    call map(range(1, tabpagenr('$')), 'extend(tpbl, tabpagebuflist(v:val))')
    for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val) && index(tpbl, v:val)==-1')
        silent execute 'bwipeout' buf
    endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: As usual, an interesting solution.  I use `map` occasionally but never `filter`; I modified my own solution to use `filter`.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rican7 I bet it is going to break not only nerdtree. E.g. Command-T opens its buffer once and does not expect it to be closed (or, at least, did not expect it to be closed in one of the past versions I happened to hit the issue). If you see such problems `&& !empty(getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype"))` may help. Or `&& index(["help", ""], getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype")) != -1` because `:help` may spawn a bunch of buffers.

Comment: @ZyX wow, you're amazing! That fixed it! Although, I had to invert the boolean logic, since the condition is on a filter: `&& empty(getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype"))`

Comment: I was going to turn this into a plugin, but someone else did it: https://github.com/arithran/vim-delete-hidden-buffers (alas with no attribution, although it's clearly cut-and-pasted from this answer).

Answer (score 11):

Extendend version of [@ZyX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459043/1527562) answer which skips modified buffers and outputs the number of buffers that was closed.

```
function! DeleteHiddenBuffers()
  let tpbl=[]
  let closed = 0
  call map(range(1, tabpagenr('$')), 'extend(tpbl, tabpagebuflist(v:val))')
  for buf in filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'bufexists(v:val) && index(tpbl, v:val)==-1')
    if getbufvar(buf, '&mod') == 0
      silent execute 'bwipeout' buf
      let closed += 1
    endif
  endfor
  echo "Closed ".closed." hidden buffers"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is slightly different way from previously posted function by Prince Goulash.  Code is untested.  It uses a function to parse the output of the `:buffers` command, which includes marker of 'h' for hidden buffers.  Something like below:

```
function! DeleteHiddenBuffers()
    redir => buffersoutput
    buffers
    redir END
    let buflist = split(buffersoutput,"\n")
    for item in filter(buflist,"v:val[5] == 'h'")
            exec 'bdelete ' . item[:2]
    endfor
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

bufexplorer.vim can manage your vim buffers. [Here to download](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42)
. you can use `:BufExplorer` to show all your vim buffers in a window. And press 'd' to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not thoroughly tested, so use it tentatively at first!

```
function! DeleteHiddenBuffers()
    let i=1
    let lastbuf=bufnr("$")
    while i <= lastbuf
        if buflisted(i) && bufwinnr(i) == -1
        sil exe "bdelete" i
        endif
        let i=i+1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Note `buflisted` checks if the buffer exists, and `bufwinnr` returns -1 if it hidden (i.e. does not have a designated window). You can call it using

```
call DeleteHiddenBuffers()
```

or create a mapping.

Comment: Looks like a decent solution, but I don't think it will work if people use tabs.  `bufwinnr` will return -1 for buffers that are open in windows on tabs other than current tab.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin: https://github.com/Asheq/close-buffers.vim
has a command `:Bdelete hidden` that closes all hidden buffers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function! DeleteBuffers(action)
"action=1 delete all unnamed buffers
"action=2 delete all unmodified buffers
"action=3 delete all buffers which are both unnamed and unmodified
"action=4 delete all hidden buffers
"action=5 delete all buffers which are both hidden and unnamed 
"action=6 delte all bufferes which are both hidden and unmodified
"action=7 delete all buffers which are all of hidden, unmodified and unnamed.
"action=8 delete all buffers which are not loaded.
    for buf in getbufinfo()
    if a:action == 1
        if strlen(buf.name) == 0
            silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
        endif  
    elseif a:action == 2
        if buf.changed == 0
            silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
        endif
    elseif a:action == 3
        if strlen(buf.name) == 0 && buf.changed == 0
            silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
        endif
    elseif a:action == 4
        if buf.hidden != 0
            silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
        endif
    elseif a:action == 5
        if buf.hidden != 0  && strlen(buf.name) == 0
           silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
         endif
    elseif a:action == 6
        if buf.hidden != 0  && buf.changed == 0
            silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
        endif
    elseif a:action == 7
         if buf.hidden != 0  && buf.changed == 0 && strlen(buf.name) == 0
             silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
         endif
    elseif a:action == 8
         if buf.loaded == 0 
              silent execute 'bwipeout!' buf.bufnr
         endif
      endif
endfor
endfunction
```

above is my DeleteBuffers function. No Complicated stuff like map, extend, filter etc... Each call can be bound to any key mapping as required in any mode. Easily modifiable as per requirements.

Answer (score -7):

Here's what I use:

```
:bufdo bd
```

No need for plugins or anything.

Comment: Technically, that does delete all of the hidden buffers. It also deletes the rest of the buffers. :)